# Vaadin CustomField with Tag has no Label

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

In my Vaadin (14.4.6) application I've got a `CustomField` like this one: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-custom-field/java-examples

When I add a `@Tag` annotation to my CustomField implementation, the label and error elements are gone.

This is how the HTML is like in Firefox **without** the `@Tag` annotation:

[image: HTML of a Vaadin CustomField without Tag annotation]

This is how the HTML is like in Firefox **with** the `@Tag` annotation:

[image: HTML of a Vaadin CustomField with Tag annotation]

Is there a way to set a custom tag name at a CustomField without losing the label and the error elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CustomField is linked to a webcomponent with the Tag vaadin-custom-field so if you add a tag it will use a different webcomponent, in your case chart-field.

Why do you want to change the tag?

Comment: Interesting info that the tag defines the webcomponent. I thought that the used webcomponent template is dependent of the Java class, not dependent of the tag. By changing the tag name I wanted the HTML code to be consistent with all the other specific HTML elements like "vaadin-text-field", "vaadin-combo-box", "vaadin-split-layout", "vaadin-vertical-layout", .... Ok, then it seems that using the `@Tag` here is just wrong in my context. Thank you!